# Elasticsearch: SearchPhaseExecutionException/Parse Failure

Tags: ruby, lucene, elasticsearch

I ran the following query on elasticsearch

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/games_201403031340/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query" : {
        "field" : { "title": "ca" }
    }
}'
```

And I got this error as a result

```
  "error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[znmo0cd5Q3S2_ymuDANqKw][games_201403031340][1]: SearchParseException[[games_201403031340][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n    \"query\" : {\n        \"field\" : { \"title\": \"ca\" }\n    }\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[games_201403031340] No query registered for [field]]; }{[znmo0cd5Q3S2_ymuDANqKw][games_201403031340][2]: SearchParseException[[games_201403031340][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n    \"query\" : {\n        \"field\" : { \"title\": \"ca\" }\n    }\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[games_201403031340] No query registered for [field]]; }{[znmo0cd5Q3S2_ymuDANqKw][games_201403031340][0]: SearchParseException[[games_201403031340][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n    \"query\" : {\n        \"field\" : { \"title\": \"ca\" }\n    }\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[games_201403031340] No query registered for [field]]; }{[znmo0cd5Q3S2_ymuDANqKw][games_201403031340][4]: SearchParseException[[games_201403031340][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n    \"query\" : {\n        \"field\" : { \"title\": \"ca\" }\n    }\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[games_201403031340] No query registered for [field]]; }{[znmo0cd5Q3S2_ymuDANqKw][games_201403031340][3]: SearchParseException[[games_201403031340][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n    \"query\" : {\n        \"field\" : { \"title\": \"ca\" }\n    }\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[games_201403031340] No query registered for [field]]; }]",
  "status" : 400
}
```

This also was in my elasticsearch log

```
[2014-03-03 14:19:15,008][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Susan Storm] [games_201403031340][1], node[znmo0cd5Q3S2_ymuDANqKw], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@f799344] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [games_201403031340][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{
    "query" : {
        "field" : { "title": "ca" }
    }
}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:586)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:489)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:474)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:467)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:239)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.sendExecuteQuery(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:202)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.sendExecuteFirstPhase(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:216)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$2.run(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [games_201403031340] No query registered for [field]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:221)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:321)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:260)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryParseElement.parse(QueryParseElement.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:574)
    ... 12 more
[2014-03-03 14:19:15,008][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Susan Storm] [games_201403031340][2], node[znmo0cd5Q3S2_ymuDANqKw], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@f799344] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [games_201403031340][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{
    "query" : {
        "field" : { "title": "ca" }
    }
}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:586)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:489)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:474)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:467)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:239)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.sendExecuteQuery(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:202)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.sendExecuteFirstPhase(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:216)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$2.run(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [games_201403031340] No query registered for [field]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:221)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:321)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:260)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryParseElement.parse(QueryParseElement.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:574)
    ... 12 more
[2014-03-03 14:19:15,008][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Susan Storm] [games_201403031340][4], node[znmo0cd5Q3S2_ymuDANqKw], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@f799344]
org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [games_201403031340][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{
    "query" : {
        "field" : { "title": "ca" }
    }
}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:586)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:489)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:474)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:467)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:239)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.sendExecuteQuery(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:202)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.sendExecuteFirstPhase(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:216)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$2.run(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [games_201403031340] No query registered for [field]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:221)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:321)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:260)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryParseElement.parse(QueryParseElement.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:574)
    ... 12 more
[2014-03-03 14:19:15,009][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Susan Storm] All shards failed for phase: [query]
[2014-03-03 14:19:15,008][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Susan Storm] [games_201403031340][0], node[znmo0cd5Q3S2_ymuDANqKw], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@f799344] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [games_201403031340][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{
    "query" : {
        "field" : { "title": "ca" }
    }
}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:586)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:489)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:474)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:467)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:239)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.sendExecuteQuery(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:202)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.sendExecuteFirstPhase(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:216)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$2.run(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [games_201403031340] No query registered for [field]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:221)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:321)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:260)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryParseElement.parse(QueryParseElement.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:574)
    ... 12 more
[2014-03-03 14:19:15,008][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Susan Storm] [games_201403031340][3], node[znmo0cd5Q3S2_ymuDANqKw], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@f799344] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [games_201403031340][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{
    "query" : {
        "field" : { "title": "ca" }
    }
}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:586)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:489)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:474)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:467)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:239)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.sendExecuteQuery(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:202)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.sendExecuteFirstPhase(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:216)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$2.run(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [games_201403031340] No query registered for [field]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:221)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:321)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:260)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryParseElement.parse(QueryParseElement.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:574)
    ... 12 more
```

Not sure whats going on, but I have no problem running a query like...

```
curl -X POST localhost:9200/games_201403031340/_suggest?pretty=true -d '
{
  "apple_game" : {
    "text" : "m",
    "completion" : {
      "field" : "title"
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: To anyone that might read this, make sure you are using the correct version of the ElasticSearch Server, I was running 1.3.2 on my local environment while my co-worker was running 1.4 and ElasticSearch Query generating class was built on top of functionality of 1.4 so my was crashing

Answer (score 11):

You also get this error when you run out of disk space on your Elastic Search volume.

Answer (score 3):

Executing in Marvel/Sense, search for **space** after /_search command. This to trigger an Parse Exception too.

Comment: omg, that was so stupid! Lost 2 hours looking for reasons, reading logs, cluster health and examining errors when the real problem was an invisible space in *sense*. Thank you, Thiago Bussiki! :)

Answer (score 3):

Check that your Elastic server has enough free disk space/RAM.

For me the disk space was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was no record for one of tables included in Searchkick. Make sure you have at least one record in each table, then `rake db:reindex:all` and try again.

Comment: This answer helped me solve my problem. I used `rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=ClassName` to reindex just one troublesome Class

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an error because Elasticsearch doesn't know what a field query is: `No query registered for [field]]`

If you're trying to find documents where the title field contains ca, you could do this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "title:ca"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get almost the same error `ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Suggester[query_string] not supported]`

Comment: The query above is for the _search endpoint, not _suggest.  Are you trying to search for ca in the title, or get suggestions?

Comment: In the first example, I am trying to search in the second I am looking for suggestions

Comment: The _search and _suggest endpoints have different syntax; they do different things.  In the original question, it looks like you're having trouble with the _search but the _suggest is working.  Is that right? If not, can you rewrite the question to make it more clear?